# Joining the same table a dynamic number of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table that contains a list of parent items and the child items that were used in production as follows

| Father Item | Child Item | Qty Used |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Parent1 | Child1 | 5 |
| Parent1 | Child2 | 6 |
| Parent1 | Child3 | 10 |

Now Child 1 can be a parent itself so i need to join the same table again linking Child1 as a child in the first table to child1 as a parent in the 2nd table to get its cost and quantity used.

My problem is that i don't know how many levels this can go, sometimes it's 4 or 5 or more. So I am trying to find a solution that can allow me to keep going down in levels until the join returns nulls because non of the child items in the level i am currently at are parents/produced items.

Is it possible to have a loop do something like that?

Comment: This is a normal hierarchical table, what is the problem you have with it ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Things would be much more clear if you would show us the result you expect

Comment: The search term you want is "recursive CTE" - most examples are manager/employee or bill of materials.